Why does the JDBC_ALREADY_CLOSED error occur in GridDB?
I am working on a Java application with GridDB and using JDBC to interact with the database. While running my application, I encountered the following error:
JDBC_ALREADY_CLOSED ERROR
Status check of client request failed. Operation may be wrong.
A method other than isClosed() was invoked for an object that has a close() method,
e.g., a Java.sql.Connection object, etc., after it has been closed.
Check the method invoking sequence.
My Code
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class GridDBJDBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            // Step 1: Establish a JDBC connection
            String url = "jdbc:gs://192.168.0.1:10001/farwa_db";
            String user = "admin";
            String password = "admin786";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            // Step 2: Execute a query
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE score > ?";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setDouble(1, 50.0);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // Step 3: Process results
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + resultSet.getString("name") + 
                                   ", Score: " + resultSet.getDouble("score"));
            }

            // Step 4: Close the connection
            connection.close();

            // Step 5: Attempt to reuse the closed connection (causes the error)
            preparedStatement.setDouble(1, 75.0); // Error occurs here
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


You cloesd the connection - why do you expect it to work?

Please include the complete stacktrace in your question.
